# Adobe Illustrator svg forrmat

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

So I wanted to know how Adobe Illustrator exports an svg, and then I created my own svg:

```
<svg class="canvas-slider" viewBox="0 0 1366 768.375">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .canvas-slider-path {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient);
      }
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="383.75" x2="1366" y2="383.75" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#2ad8ff"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#2a61ff"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path class="canvas-slider-path" d="M 0 768.375 l 1366 0 l 0 768.375 l -1366 0 Z"/>
</svg>
```

without changing anything, I tried open it with Adobe Illustrator and then immediately export it as an svg, and then I notice the code change to:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1366" height="768.375" viewBox="0 0 1366 768.375">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient);
      }
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" y1="-384.5625" x2="1366" y2="-384.5625" gradientTransform="matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 768)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#2ad8ff"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#2a61ff"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <title>test</title>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M0,768.375H1366V1536.75H0Z" transform="translate(0 -768.375)"/>
</svg>
```

can someone explain it to me the changes on the `d` property from the `path`? and also why does it has a `transform` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a great explanation about svg path line commands:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Uppercase letters specify absolute coordinates, lowercase letters specify relative coordinates.

Based on that, the two examples result in identical rectangles.

1)
d="M 0 768.375 l 1366 0 l 0 768.375 l -1366 0 Z"

- Move to absolute coords (x = 0, y = 768.375)
- Draw a relative line, move right by (x = 1366, y = 0)
- Draw a relative line, move down by (x = 0, y = 768.375)
- Draw a relative line, move left by (x = 1366 (negative sign shows we are going back), y = 0)
- Close the path, get back to the starting point

2)
d="M 0, 768.375 H 1366 V 1536.75 H 0 Z" transform="translate(0 -768.375)"

- Move to absolute coords (x = 0, y = 768.375)
- Move horizontally to absolute coord (x = 1366)
- Move vertically to absolute coord (y = 1536.75)
- Move horizontally to absolute coord (x = 0)
- Close the path, get back to the starting point

Illustrator only did a relative -> absolute transformation.
In your first example the rectangle is not in the viewBox="0 0 1366 768.375", and I think the transformation was applied to visually move the rectangle back to (x = 0, y = 0);

Comment: your explanation is very clear, but what about adding an anchor? I don't see it anywhere on the MDN article you gave to me. Thanks anyway!